# How can I parse JSON data from the college scorecard API onto an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, json, api

I was able to pull data from the college scorecard API into JSON objects using this template repeated a few times over:

```
def data_public_net_price():
    url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json'
    payload = {
        'api_key': "api_key_string",
        '_fields': ','.join([
            '2015.cost.net_price.public.by_income_level.0-30000',
            '2015.cost.net_price.public.by_income_level.30001-48000',
            '2015.cost.net_price.public.by_income_level.48001-75000',
            '2015.cost.net_price.public.by_income_level.75001-110000',
            '2015.cost.net_price.public.by_income_level.110001-plus',
        ]),
        'school.operating': '1',
        '2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors': 'true',
        '2015.student.size__range': '1..',
        'school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range': '1..3',
        'school.degrees_awarded.highest__range': '2..4',
        'id': '240444',
    }
    data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    for result in data['results']:
        print result

data_public_net_price()
```

I haven't created an HTML document yet, as I'm unsure how I should parse this data onto an HTML file. In your opinion, what would be the best way to do that?

Here's the output when I run the program:

```
{u'2015.student.share_firstgeneration_parents.middleschool': 0.008181
5375, u'2015.student.share_firstgeneration_parents.somecollege': 0.82
91139241, u'2015.student.share_firstgeneration_parents.highschool': 0
.1627045384}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a template engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/).

And for your html structure it depends on how you want to show the data. You could show inside a `<ul>` with `<li>`, or some `<div>` anywhere, really depends on what you are trying to achieve.